# Sorting an increasing number in an array in Javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays

I'm running into a error in stopping the execution when a lower number occurs in the data of an array

`Let seat1 = [2, 5, 6, 9, 2, 12, 18];` 
console should log the values till it gets to 9 since 
`2 < 5 < 6 < 9` 
then omit 2 since `9 > 2`
then continue from `12 < 18.`

```js
let num = [2, 5, 6, 9, 2, 12, 18];
    
    for (let i = 0; i < num.length; i++) {
        if ((num[i] + 1) > num[i]) {
    
            console.log(num[i])
        } else {
            console.log('kindly fix')
        }
    }
```

Comment: `num[i] + 1` should be `num[i + 1]`

Answer (score 3):

Use [`Array.reduce()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce) to create a new array without the items that are not larger than the last item in the accumulator (`acc`) or `-Infinity` if it's the 1st item:

```js
const num = [2, 5, 6, 9, 2, 3, 12, 18];

const result = num.reduce((acc, n) => {
  if(n > (acc[acc.length - 1] || -Infinity)) acc.push(n);

  return acc;
}, []);

console.log(result);
```

Answer (score 1):

simple answer using if and for -

```js
let num = [2, 5, 6, 9, 2 , 3, 12, 16, 9, 18];
let max = 0;

for (let i = 0; i < num.length; i++) 
{ 
   if ((i == 0) || (num[i] > max)) {
     max = num[i];
     console.log (num[i]);
   }
}
```

Comment: Fails with `[2, 5, 6, 9, 2 ,3, 12, 18];`

Comment: @charlietfl what should happen in that case?

Comment: Assuming OP only wants sequential values I assume `3` should be omitted also but needs clarification

Comment: Your if statement is always checking i == 0 every iteration, instead you should just set max to a value that is smaller than num[0]. Refer to my answer.

Answer (score 1):

You could filter the array by storing the last value who is greater than the last value.

```js
var array = [2, 5, 6, 9, 2, 3, 12, 18],
    result = array.filter((a => b => a < b && (a = b, true))(-Infinity));

console.log(result)
```

Comment: What. What's this? `(a => b => a < b && (a = b, true))(-Infinity)` How is the double arrow working here? never seen that before. Mind explaining it?

Comment: @briosheje, it is a closure over `a`, which is invoked with `-Infinity`. `b` is the value of each item in the array. the rest is a condition and a part with a comma operator which returns `true` at the end after assigning `b` to `a`.

Comment: Oh. Interesting. So, `a` holds the lowest (current) value in the array, right? never saw that before. Also, didn't know that `(a = b, true)` would return true. Thanks for sharing and explaining.

Comment: `a` contains the last valid greater value.

Comment: Right, sorry. That's a clever approach.

Answer (score 0):

Store the max value and check num[i] against the current max. If num[i] is bigger, log it and set the new max value. Initial max value should be first num value but smaller so it doesn't fail on the first check.

```js
let num = [2, 5, 6, 9, 2, 12, 18];
let max = num[0] - 1;

for (let i = 0; i < num.length; i++) {
  if (num[i] > max) {
    console.log(num[i]);
    max = num[i];
  }
}
```

Answer (score -2):

```js
let num = [2, 5, 6, 9, 2, 12, 18];
let result = num.sort((a, b) => a - b).filter((elem, pos, arr) => {
     return arr.indexOf(elem) == pos;
  })
 console.log(result)
```

Comment: It should yield `[2, 5, 6, 9, 12, 18]`

Comment: FYI: [Sorting in JavaScript: Shouldn't returning a boolean be enough for a comparison function?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24080785)

Comment: @adiga Thanks for this important comment